# Formatting XML data for testing

Tags: xml

I have data in a XML file that I need to extract and display in a certain way so I can run some tests.

The data in the XML is shown like this:

```
<is:Person>
    <is:PersonId/>
    <is:NationalIdentificationNumber/>
    <is:Name>
        <dg:Title/>
```

What I need is it to show up like this:

```
is:Person/is:PersonID
is:Person/is:NationalIdentificationNumber
is:Person/is:Name/
is:Person/is:Name/dg:Title
```

...

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't know what to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in your question is not well-formed XML. It lacks closing tags.

Once the closing tags are added, you can use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) on it to get the structure:

```
$ xmlstarlet el [input file]
```

The output will be almost what you have shown in your question:

```
is:Person
is:Person/is:PersonId
is:Person/is:NationalIdentificationNumber
is:Person/is:Name
is:Person/is:Name/dg:Title
```

It will complain that `is` and `dg` are undefined namespaces. XML does not require the use of namespaces, and when namespaces are not used, an XML validator should accept colons in element names. However, I do not know of a flag that will make xmlstarlet not complain about this.

Comment: I've appended `</is:Name></is:Person>` to the XML shown in the question. You should read up on the basics of XML because this is really basic.

Comment: Use redirection: `xmlstarlet el [input file] > [path to file you want to store output in]`.